# caddy-docker-proxy to host port

Tags: docker, reverse-proxy, docker-compose

I'm running cockpit on port 9090 on my host machine.

In a docker container on the host is the [caddy-docker-proxy](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/caddy-docker-proxy).

The reverse proxy (RP) container is linked to the host ports 80 and 443.

Is there any way I can use the caddy-docker-proxy to access port 9090 on the host machine?

I've tried using the cockpit-ws docker image but it doesn't contain the webserver and as such I have the same issue.

I don't know how I might add a custom caddyfile to the RP nor how I might create a dummy container.

See related [github issue](https://github.com/lucaslorentz/caddy-docker-proxy/issues/278)

Comment: Also need a `caddy` tag. [https://caddyserver.com/](https://caddyserver.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I've added a few lines to the caddy docker-compose.yml and altered the host cockpit conf file:

docker-compose.yml:

```
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
labels:
  caddy: pluto.thechubbypanda.net
  caddy.reverse_proxy: "host.docker.internal:9090"
```

/etc/cockpit/cockpit.conf:

```
[WebService]
AllowUnencrypted = true
ProtocolHeader = X-Forwarded-Proto
```

Comment: Cannot login with that, it gives me "Connection failed"

Comment: Try restarting caddy

Comment: No budge. I suspect it is because I am using staging LE certificates, and my connection is not secure.

Comment: Good luck. Isn't the whole point of using caddy the automatic cert management haha?